# How to get onNewIntent() in a Navigation Fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to use Navigation component in my android project, in order to achieve this, I have refactored my app to be fragment-based, but it raises a problem that I don't know how to pass `onNewIntent()` in my `MainActivity` to my Navigation Fragments.

So `MainActivity` is a `NavHost`, to make it simple, saying that I have a fragment as the start destination, how can I get `onNewIntent()` inside this fragment from `MainActivity`?

***UPDATE***
Also, is there a way to get the reference of the current presented fragment, like the one currently held by `NavHost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On new intent , you can do something like

```
    val navigationController = nav_host_fragment.findNavController()

    if (navigationController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.fragmentA) {
        (nav_host_fragment.childFragmentManager.fragments[0] as FragmentA).doSomething()

    }
```

Here you can pass any values to the function doSomething()

Answer (score -1):

You can use in MainAcitivy class this:

```
private Fragment fragment;

fragment = new FragmentTry();

getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentid, fragment)
            .commit();
```

Comment: but because I set my fragment as the start destination, it will be initialised automatically by Android itself,  is there any way to get the reference of this fragment without reinit it?

Comment: I don't understand, could you make the description?

Comment: I follow this https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started to build up my navigation graph. I put a defaultNavHost in my MainActivity's xml file, and then specify the start destination in `nav_graph`, which is my fragment. By doing so, when I `setContentView` in `MyActivity`, it will automatically create an instance of my fragment. So I don't control the instantiation of this fragment.

Comment: @HaoyuanTang It is possible to get the reference of the current fragment. You can call `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` which will return a list, and then if you use a tag (if not, you should) then you can match the tags while looping on the fragments on the list. If the tags match, then it means you fetched the current fragment itself.

Comment: If you're against using tags (or for some reason you cannot use them), since I assume you have one fragment by each class, you can do a check like `if (fragment instanceof MyFragment)` to determine the fragment you target.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul That sounds good! Just curious, is it possible to get the current fragment being presented, or in other words, the top fragment in the navigation stack, in `MyActivity` dynamically without hardcoding the identifier of a specific fragment? Coz in my actual project, the app only has one Activity and multiple fragments, every fragment should be able to handle the NFC intent, and seems only Activity can get the intent from `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: @HaoyuanTang It is possible, but not directly, and you should be careful about memory leaks and always detach fragments. You can attach a `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` (I believe that's what it's called) on the activity with calling `getSupportFragmentManager().registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(callbacks, boolean recursive)` and the fragment that is attached the last should be the one currently presented. It also provides a complete control over all fragments by requirements.

Comment: For the comment above: If you register another fragment from fragment, you should set `boolean recursive` as true on callbacks.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul Thank you very much, seems this will save my life!

Comment: @HaoyuanTang Glad that it helped.